# Mocked Class & Asserting Method Calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Stumped on how to mock a class and be able to assert that its' methods are called with some arguments. When I assert the call i get a "Not called" assertion but, I can see the method call in the `mock_calls` attribute.

`sandbox/module.py`

```py
class Subject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        reference = Reference(*args, **kwargs)
        reference.method_a(*args)


class Reference(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def method_a(self, *args):
        pass
```

`test.py`

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from sandbox.module import Subject


class TestSandbox(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('sandbox.module.Reference')
    def test_method_calls(self, mock_reference):
        subject = Subject()
        subject.run(1, 2, 3, x=44, y=55, z=66)
        mock_reference.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3, x=44, y=55, z=66)
        mock_reference.method_a.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3)
```

The result is

```
AssertionError: Expected call: method_a(1, 2, 3)  
Not called
```

The value of `mock_reference.mock_calls` is

```
[
    call(1, 2, 3, x=44, y=55, z=66), 
    call().method_a(1, 2, 3)
]
```

If I access call as `call().method_a` I can access the method details but, the `mock_calls` gets a item `call()` added to it. Which could change `assert_called_once_with` in a way i wouldn't expect and, doesn't feel quite right. Furthermore, if `autospec=True` is used I need to pass the params again. Using just `call` as in `mock_reference.call.method_a` does not work either.

Output of `mock_calls` when accessing `call().method_a.mock_calls`

```py
mock_reference().method_a.mock_calls

[
    call(1, 2, 3, x=44, y=55, z=66), 
    call().method_a(1, 2, 3),
    call()
]    

mock_reference.assert_called_once_with(1, 2, 3)

AssertionError: Expected 'Reference' to be called once. Called 2 times.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You mocked a class, yet the second method is called on instance. Change

```
mock_reference.method_a.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3)
```

to

```
mock_reference.return_value.method_a.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Fantastic. This works in a clear and understandable way. Thank you

Comment: Works perfect! Wish I came across with this post 6 hours ago instead of wasting them on trying other stuff