# Throw exception after first call

Tags: python, django, mocking, magicmock

I have a loop where I handle adding records to a zip file. I have mocked my zipfile object and I want to raise a exception to verify that my logic for handling large zipfiles will work correctly.

is there a way with MagicMocks or plain mocks to accept the first call, but raise an exception on the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with a generator and Mock side_effect

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

def sample_generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    raise Exception()

gen = sample_generator()

def sideeffect():
    global gen
    for x in gen:
        return x


m = Mock(side_effect=sideeffect)
m() #1
m() #2
m() #3
```

you can get:

```
File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
   m() #3
   ....
   raise Exception()
Exception
```

I'm sure you can make it slightly cleaner with some effort, but it should solve your basic problem

Comment: shoot, this works to allow the first call, and throw on the second, but what if I want to allow a third call to be successful?

Comment: @NathanTregillus take a look to my answer it cover your comment too.

Comment: I didn't edit you answer to cover the OP request just because I should change it too much. I did it in the past http://stackoverflow.com/a/28924186/4101725 . So filled a new answer.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico feel free to edit in your points, it's simpler anyway and does cover both cases required by the OP. btw - down-vote is not work of mine...

Answer (score 29):

The simplest way is to use [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) that accept either iterable, callable or Exception (class or instance)

> Alternatively `side_effect` can be an exception class or instance. In this case the exception will be raised when the mock is called.

As showed in [Quick Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) you can use `side_effect` to raise an exception simply by

> ```
> >>> mock = Mock(side_effect=KeyError('foo'))
> >>> mock()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  ...
> KeyError: 'foo'
> ```

Moreover you can use list and Exception together in `side_effect` assignment. So the simplest way to do what you need is something like this:

```
>>> m = Mock(side_effect=[1, KeyError("bar"), 3])
>>> m("a")
1
>>> m("b")
 ...
KeyError: 'bar'
>>> m("c")
3
```

An other way to do it can be use a callable to write the logic of how your mock should react. In this case you are free to chose if it based on arguments or your test's state.

Comment: seriously. I hate when people do that! I like your answer! this KeyError, is this a special method? I want this to throw a specific exception, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @NathanTregillus I used `KeyError` just as example. You can use every kind of `Exception` you want.

Comment: @maazza yes of course... `m` is a mocked object. Even if you mean a _patched_ object the answer is yes again: `patch` patch an object with a `Mock` instance.

Comment: When patching you need to define the side effects this way `m.side_effect = [1, KeyError(), 3]`